# Postgres upper function on turkish character does not return expected result

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, turkish

It looks like postgres `upper/lower` function does not handle select characters in Turkish character set.

```
select upper('Aaı'), lower('Aaİ') from mytable;
```

returns :

```
AAı, aaİ
```

instead of :

```
AAI, aai
```

Note that normal english characters are converted correctly, but not the Turkish I (lower or upper)

Postgres version: `9.2 32 bit`

Database encoding (Same result in any of these): `UTF-8, WIN1254, C`

Client encoding:

```
 UTF-8, WIN1254, C
```

OS: `Windows 7 enterprise edition 64bit`

SQL functions `lower` and `upper` return the following same bytes for ı and İ on UTF-8 encoded database

```
\xc4b1    
\xc4b0
```

And the following on WIN1254 (Turkish) encoded database

```
\xfd      
\xdd
```

I hope my investigation is wrong, and there is something I missed.

Comment: Are you sure this is PostgreSQL? `dual` is an Oracle-ism. Also, what's the database and client encoding, and the platform it's running on? Paste the result from: `SELECT getdatabaseencoding(), current_setting('client_encoding'), current_setting('lc_ctype'), current_setting('lc_collate'), version();`

Comment: Not that you can't create a `dual` table with one row in it like Oracle's bizarre `dual`, but why would you? Maybe you're using EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus with its Oracle compatiblity layer?

Comment: getdatabaseencoding | current_setting |   current_setting   |   current_setting   |                           version
---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 UTF8                | WIN1254         | Turkish_Turkey.1254 | Turkish_Turkey.1254 | PostgreSQL 9.2.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit

Comment: Same was the result when database encoding has been changed to WIN1254

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help, please treat dual as any other table.  I mentioned it as dual just for convenience.

Comment: OK, so it's a UTF-8-encoded DB in the turkish locale. What do other Windows programs do when you ask to upper-case `AAı`? Like Excel, Word, Python, etc? In other words, is the result consistent with other tools on the platform?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Your problem *is* 100% Windows.**  (Or rather Microsoft Visual Studio, which PostgreSQL was built with, to be more precise.)

For the record, SQL `UPPER` ends up calling Windows' [`LCMapStringW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318700.aspx) (via [`towupper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45119yx3.aspx) via [`str_toupper`](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=xz8DJIKrn5U-bfV7tNYBJu0fx6Q&cid=eD%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BOmLT58hyw&s=str_toupper&pp=0&fp=305491&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=0&ml=1&me=1&md=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B1&browser=Default#L1610)) with *almost* all the right parameters (locale 1055 Turkish for a `UTF-8`-encoded, `Turkish_Turkey` database),

**but**

the Visual Studio Runtime (`towupper`) does not set the [`LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING`](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/11/279942.aspx) bit in `LCMapStringW`'s *dwMapFlags*.  (I can confirm that setting it does the trick.)  **This is not considered a bug at Microsoft; it is by design, and will probably not ever be "fixed"** (oh the joys of legacy.)

You have three ways out of this:

- implement @Sorrow's wrapper solution (or write your own native function replacement (DLL).)
- **run your PostgreSQL instance on e.g. Ubuntu** which exhibits the right behaviour for Turkic locales (@Sorrow confirmed that it works for him); this is probably the simplest and cleanest way out.
- drop in **a patched 32-bit `MSVCR100.DLL`** in your PostgreSQL `bin` directory (but although `UPPER` and `LOWER` would work, other things such as collation may continue to fail -- again, at the Windows level. YMMV.)

---

**For completeness** (and nostalgic fun) **ONLY**, here is the procedure to patch a Windows system (but remember, unless you'll be managing this PostgreSQL instance from cradle to grave you may cause a lot of grief to your successor(s); whenever deploying a new test or backup system from scratch you or your successor(s) would have to remember to apply the patch again -- and if let's say you one day upgrade to PostgreSQL 10, which say uses `MSVCR120.DLL` instead of `MSVCR100.DLL`, then you'll have to try your luck with patching the new DLL, too.)  **On a test system**

- use [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to open `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.DLL`
- save the DLL right away with the same name under you PostgreSQL `bin` directory (do not attempt to copy the file using Explorer or the command line, they might copy the 64bit version)
- with the file still open in HxD, go to *Search > Replace*, pick *Datatype: Hexvalues*, then

  - search for...... `4E 14 33 DB 3B CB 0F 84  41 12 00 00 B8 00 01 00 00`
  - replace with... `4E 14 33 DB 3B CB 0F 84  41 12 00 00 B8 00 01 00 01`
  - ...then once more...
  - search for...... `FC 51 6A 01 8D 4D 08 51  68 00 02 00 00 50 E8 E2`
  - replace with... `FC 51 6A 01 8D 4D 08 51  68 00 02 00 01 50 E8 E2`
- ...and re-save under the PostgreSQL `bin` directory, then restart PostgreSQL and re-run your query.

  - if your query still does not work (make sure your database is UTF-8 encoded with `Turkish_Turkey` for both `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE`) open `postgres.exe` in [32-bit Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and make sure it indicates it loads `MSVCR100.DLL` from the PostgreSQL `bin` directory.
  - if all functions well copy the patched DLL to the production PostgreSQL `bin` directory and restart.

BUT REMEMBER, the moment you move the data off the Ubuntu system or off the patched Windows system to an unpatched Windows system you will have the problem again, and you may be unable to import this data back on Ubuntu if the Windows instance introduced duplicates in a `citext` field or in a `UPPER`/`LOWER`-based function index.

Comment: Getting the same issue on macOS, so clearly not "100% Windows".

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert, you can still upgrade to Linux as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

It seems *to me* that your problem is related to Windows. This is how it looks on Ubuntu (Postgres 8.4.14), database encoding UTF-8:

```
test=# select upper('Aaı'), lower('Aaİ');
 upper | lower
-------+-------
 AAI   | aai
(1 row)
```

My recommendation would be - if you have to use Windows - to write a stored procedure that will do the conversion for you. Use built-in `replace`: `replace('abcdefabcdef', 'cd', 'XX')` returns `abXXefabXXef`. There might be a more optimal solution, I do not claim that this approach is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed bug in PostgreSQL (still not fixed, even in current git tree).
Proof: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/port/pgstrcasecmp.c

PostgreSQL developers even mention specifically those Turkish characters there:

> SQL99 specifies Unicode-aware case normalization, which we don't yet
>   have the infrastructure for. Instead we use tolower() to provide a
>   locale-aware translation.
>   However, **there are some locales where this is not right either (eg, Turkish may do strange things with 'i' and 'I').**
>   Our current compromise is to use tolower() for characters with
>   the high bit set, and use an ASCII-only downcasing for 7-bit
>   characters.

`pg_upper()` implemented in this file is extremely simplistic (as its companion `pg_tolower()`):

```
unsigned char
pg_toupper(unsigned char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            ch += 'A' - 'a';
    else if (IS_HIGHBIT_SET(ch) && islower(ch))
            ch = toupper(ch);
    return ch;
}
```

As you can see, this code does not treat its parameter as Unicode code point, and cannot possibly work 100% correctly, unless currently selected locale happens to be the one that we care for (like Turkish non-unicode locale) and OS-provided non-unicode `toupper()` is working correctly.

This is really sad, I just hope that this will be solved in upcoming PostgreSQL releases...

Comment: Actually this answer is incorrect. SQL `UPPER` does not call [`pg_toupper`](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=bcsvrWmEl-5AqSX9_c_wS5xcEv8&cid=eDOmLT58hyw&s=pg_toupper#L100), but rather [`str_toupper`](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=xz8DJIKrn5U-bfV7tNYBJu0fx6Q&cid=eDOmLT58hyw&s=str_toupper&pp=0&fp=305491&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=0&ml=1&me=1&md=‌​1#L1610), which converts everything to `wchar_t` on supported platforms then uses towupper, which means it depends on Microsoft's implementation (and is consistent with what @Sorrow reported, e.g. Ubuntu `towupper` is OK.)

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem explained above. It seems the problem only occurs with the conversion of 'I' to 'ı' and 'i' to 'İ'. As a workaround just replace those characters directly as below before calling lower or upper functions:

```
SELECT lower(replace('IİĞ', 'I', 'ı')) -> ıiğ
SELECT upper(replace('ıiğ', 'i', 'İ')) -> IİĞ
```

Answer (score 0):

From PostgreSQL v15 on, you would solve the problem by using ICU locals rather than C library locales for your database:

```
CREATE DATABASE for_turkish
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE "tr-TR"
   LOCALE "tr_TR"
   TEMPLATE template0;
```