# PostgreSQL lower() and upper() not working with some Turkish characters

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, special-characters

In PostgreSQL 11.4, I realized that `lower()` and `upper()` methods are not working with some of Turkish characters i.e. ***'İ'*** and ***'ı'***.

```
select lower('İ'); -- returns 'İ' instead of 'i'
select upper('ı'); -- returns 'ı' instead of 'I'
```

Although the methods works properly with the other Turkish characters i.e. "ç, ö, ş, ğ, ü", there seems to be not a proper workaround except from `replace` or some of the procedures. So, I am wondering whether or not this is a bug and it will be solved in the next version of PostgreSQL. If not yet, is there a smarter workaround regarding to this problem at least for now?

***Note:*** I use Windows 10, but I am not sure if the problem is directly related to Windows.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029824/postgres-upper-function-on-turkish-character-does-not-return-expected-result